# Upload failed You need to use an SDK with a version number of 29 or lower

Tags: android, bundle

When trying to upload apk or app bundle aab on google play store getting following error
Upload failed

You need to use an SDK with a version number of 29 or lower.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.starsignature.app"
        minSdkVersion 1
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.2"
    }
```

**Update 24 Feb 2022**

google play store getting following error
Upload failed

`You need to use an SDK with a version number of 32 or lower.`

`build.gradle`:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.test"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 32
// rest of the build.gradle file
```

[image: Error message from Play Store Console]

Comment: Post your Gradle.

Comment: Are you uploading first version ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya after setting  maxSDKVersion=29 in androidManifest.xml it started working. but I am blocked from answering on this site

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya  Now after  2 yrs i ma getting same error again  only 29 is not changed to 31 in the error message..   What is the meaning of this message ? you need to use sdk version 31 or lower means does google want to say I am using SDK version above 31 ?   how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I had this issue when trying to upload my app to the playstore. Could not figure out how to fix it even after updating my gradle and gradle plugins. Ended up complying by using a lower version..